# Is it possible to use WebChannelFactory to make requests to WebAPI/OdataController functions/actions?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, servicecontract, odatacontroller, webchannelfactory

I have implemented OdataController(s) for my Web-API.
Is it possible to use a ChannelFactory (or WebChannelFactory) to communicate with the Web-API, specifically i would like to call custom Functions and/or Actions.

Of course, the OdataController i have created does implement a ServiceContract.
But i am not sure if this is possible because of the url/namespace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the answer is a resounding YES. I just implemented the service contract and set up Routing to make the service operations work.